# Is it possible to avoid using file paging on Windows CE 6 from the application side?

Tags: operating-system, windows-ce, paging

On WindowsCE 6.0 the default OS paging settings are a bit small as discussed here
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2008/01/19/paging-and-the-windows-ce-paging-pool.aspx

I cannot convince OS providers to fix such issues so I'm interested in whether there is a suggested workaround from the application side where we are impacted by excessive paging/thrashing.

Theoretically, a smaller exe would help but I'm not convinced of that.  I'm also experimenting with avoiding all memory mapping of files.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the paging pool size when creating the OS image, see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa915364.aspx).

If your OS image is third party (or you don't control it), then you can try to set the paging parameters at runtime using [IOCTL_HAL_GET_POOL_PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa916094.aspx) IOCTL call.

Also check this link for more information about [WinCE paging pools](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ce_base/archive/2008/01/19/paging-and-the-windows-ce-paging-pool.aspx).

Comment: the link you refer to indicates that "Only the OEM of a device can set the pool size; applications cannot change it."  is this accurate based on your experience?

Comment: Well, changing the pool size impacts all the applications. The OEM should be responsible with this aspect. It wouldn't be really nice if every application would start to modify the paging pool size.

Comment: agreed.  i was just unclear based on your initial answer regarding the GET_POOL ioctl. Thanks.