# Is it possible to make an WinCE exe non-pageable?

Tags: windows-ce, paging, exe

On WinCE 6, i am seeing excessive page thrashing because the default loader paging settings are very low.  I cannot fix this at the OS level so i must fix it at the application level.  My hope is to get my application out of the business of paging completely.  Is this possible?

Referring to this, it may be: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms933104.aspx

...but that may only be for device drivers on ROM.  Anyone know more definitively?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to avoid using file paging on Windows CE 6 from the application side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11199397/is-it-possible-to-avoid-using-file-paging-on-windows-ce-6-from-the-application-s)

Comment: i feel like this question is more specific and thus more relevant.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is yes. There are linker settings for this.

Comment: Ok, any hints on *which* settings are useful?